# How can I pivot and then calculate data?

Tags: sql, pivot, calculated-field

Pretty new to SQL here. Thank you so much to anyone reading this.

I have a table

```
ProductID, Year, Sales
------------------------
Product1     2019   100
Product1     2018    50
```

With a lot of products, but the two years are always 2019 and 2018.

I need to show the 100 products that had the biggest % increase in sales.

I believe that this requires "pivoting" the data, so that you can calculate the 2019 (as one column) and 2018 (second column) difference in a third column called "% increase."

But I'm totally stuck--Ive never done anything this difficult in SQL before.

Help?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be this, which would help you if there are more than one record per product - year:

```
SELECT 
    ProductId, 
    Sales_2018, 
    Sales_2019,
    (Sales_2019 - Sales_2018) / Sales_2018 * 100 AS Percentage_increase
FROM (SELECT
        ProductID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2018 THEN Sales END) AS Sales_2018, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2019 THEN Sales END) AS Sales_2019
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY ProductID)
ORDER BY (Sales_2019 - Sales_2018) / Sales_2018 DESC
```

Comment: Depending on dbms used, you could need to multiply with 100.0 to avoid _integer division_ issues.

Comment: There was more than one per year! Thank you, this is so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with self-join on almost any SQL engine.
Please find the sample implementation below.
You may need to fix some depending on the dialect that you use.

```sql
SELECT
  a.ProductId,
  (1.0 * b.Sales / a.Sales - 1.0) AS IncreaseRate
FROM
  tbl AS a
INNER JOIN
  tbl AS b
ON
  a.ProductId = b.ProductId
  AND a.year = 2018
  AND b.year = 2019
ORDER BY
  IncreaseRate DESC
LIMIT 100
```